# In Azure, how do I see CPU consumption for an app service, split on web apps?

Tags: azure, azure-app-services

One App Service Plan can host multiple web apps.

How do I see how much CPU is consumed by each individual web app in the app service plan?

Ideally, I want to see a line graph with each web app as it's own line.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor gives you an overview of the CPU usage of your apps while with Azure Webapp Diagnose and Solve Problem feature shows the average CPU percentage consumer by app per instance not just the overview. And it's more detailed in the metric.If you want to know the app plan instead go to  App service Plan -> Overview -> CPU Percentage chart. ( overall CPU utilization of the resource in the app service plan)